# kendo mcv grid row formatting not maintained after drag and drop between grids

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**Issue:**
The result of a drag-n-drop from one grid to another (both directions) results with the row data not aligning properly with the appropriate header.

Before drag-n-drop:
[image]

After (row is dropped into another table, then dropped back to the originating table)
[image]

For brevity, I'll just post the column definitions for the grids. The grids are using the same model but not all the columns are visible in both grids.

Grid1:

```
  ...
    .Name("Group1")
    .Columns(columns =>
           {
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.TransactionId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeName);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagDate).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagCreatedById).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagCreatedBy).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.Reason).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.Score).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" });
                        columns.Bound(e => e.NumberOfTransactions).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" });
                        columns.Bound(e => e.TotalAmount).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" });
                    })
  ...
```

Grid 2:

```
  ...
   .Name("Group2")
   .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.TransactionId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeId).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeName);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagDate);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagCreatedById).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.FlagCreatedBy);
              columns.Bound(e => e.Reason);
              columns.Bound(e => e.Score).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" });
              columns.Bound(e => e.NumberOfTransactions).Hidden();
              columns.Bound(e => e.TotalAmount).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" });
          })
  ...
```

The drop javascript:

```
   group1.kendoDropTarget({
        drop: function (e) {
            console.log("e.draggable.currentTarget: %O", e.draggable.currentTarget);

            e.dropTarget.append($(e.draggable.currentTarget).clone());
            $(e.draggable.currentTarget).remove();
        },
        group: "gridGroup2"
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of playing with the DOM - which is not a good practice in this case, imo - try to copy and add only the data to the target grid.

```
drop: function(e) {
    var sourceGrid = $(e.draggable.element).data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = sourceGrid.dataItem(e.draggable.currentTarget);

    $(e.dropTarget).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.add(dataItem);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/useYO/2)